# I have a problem with link datagridview and custome database column

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, datagridview

```
private void Purchases_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
com.Connection = con;
con.Open();
com.CommandText = "select * from Items";
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da7 = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
da7.Fill(dt7);
ComboColumn.DataSource = dt7;
ComboColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
com.Connection = con;
com.CommandText = "select ID from Items where Name = '" + ComboColumn + "' ";
con.Open();
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataReader dr;
dr = com.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    string id = (string)dr["ID"].ToString();
}
con.Close();
}
```

I have sql db table contains ID and Items.
also, I have winform and I'm using DataGrid type "DataGridViewComboBoxColumn" to select the items from db table and it's working perfectly
now, The problem is I need to show the following "ID column" to the second column in DGV while I selec[image]ting the items from "DataGridViewComboBoxColumn".
So, I need help to link a specific column in database which is (ID) with a specific column on datagrid column type "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn" when user select items from the gdv ComboBoxColumn.

note: 1st scop of code working and giving me items from db.
2nd scop of code not working and I can't handle it for retrieve ID from db table!!

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is wide open to injection attacks. You *need* to ensure you properly parametrise your SQL statements; don't blindly inject values.

Comment: okay @Larnu. the main task now looking away to solve my question after that I'll be closing the bug

Comment: Fix the security flaw first, then worry about getting the code to give the results you want.

Comment: @Larnu there is no release yet even the whole project will no published unless the task done!

Comment: [Duplicate post from a sock puppet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64343575/1070452)

Comment: The code is already storing all rows from the Items table in `ComboColumn.DataSource` so there is no need to query the database again in `dataGridView1_CellContentClick`.  Also that unneeded query makes no sense; `Name = '" + ComboColumn + "' "` does not produce what you think it does.  Once you figure out how to get the value selected in the dropdown, use that value to query the DataTable stored in `ComboColumn.DataSource`. Using `CellContentClick` to initiate the ID retrieval is also strange.

Comment: @TnTinMn could you help me with code, please

Comment: Any help guys or any soulutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here!

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{

```
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboBoxCell = (row.Cells[2] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell);

           
            comboBoxCell.Items.Add("Select Goods");

            
            comboBoxCell.Value = "Select Goods";

            
            DataTable dt_1 = this.GetData("SELECT ID,Name from Goods");

           
            foreach (DataRow drow in dt_1.Rows)
            {
                
                string customerId = drow[0].ToString();

               
                comboBoxCell.Items.Add(drow[0] + "-" + drow[1]);

                
                if (customerId != "3")
                {
                   
                    if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == customerId)
                    {
                        comboBoxCell.Value = drow[1];
                    }
                }
            }
```